# how to use sub query in where condition of another query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a variable with value as the result of following query

```
select concat_ws(',',name,age) from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id 
where table1.height=150
```

its result stored in varible **$result**,in another page i want use this $result on a new query in where condition as the following

```
select address, state form table1 
where (**select concat_ws(',',name,age) from table1 inner join table2 
on table1.id=table2.id**)as val=$result
```

how can i use this condition in query?

Comment: Can you tell what actually you are trying to do? *May be* we can help you to do the same even without using a sub-query.

Comment: With which field are you comparing the result of the first query? Currently you are comparing the same query. I.e. You are doing something like this: `SELECT X, Y, Z FROM MyTable WHERE (SELECT A FROM MyTable) = (SELECT A FROM MyTable);`

Comment: Normally you could just use the variable when constructing your SQL statement in PHP in order to put it into the WHERE clause. However, from the statement "in another page" it sounds like $result isn't getting set on the page you want to use it on. You need to pass that variable to the new page or recalculate the value. Variables from a previous page load are not in scope unless they are stored as a session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand why you can't use somthing simple like this :

```
SELECT address, state FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id 
WHERE concat_ws(',',name,age) = '$result'
```